# Should I leave old events in my sitemap?

Tags: sitemap

Should I leave old events in my sitemap that have passed, or remove them?  The sitemap is quite huge and I didn't know if that was OK.

Answer (score 2):

I can see three possible courses of action:

1. If having old events still listed in search engines is important, then it could be worth leaving them in your sitemap. This would be handy if your events are likely to be searched for from outside your site (e.g. in Google).
2. If you want to keep the pages available to users on your site but you don't need them listed externally, then remove them from your sitemap and add a `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` to past events.
3. If you don't need past events accessible at all, then you can remove the pages from your site and set 301 redirects to a generic Events page.

If you're worried about the size of your sitemap then you may want to think about splitting up your sitemap and using a [Sitemap Index](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index).